# port visible but not accessable

Tags: router, ip, port, modem

I have port 80 open through my router, I have disabled my firewall, and canyouseeme.org sees port 80.  yet I can not navigate to my IP address which is my web server.

How can my port be visible yet I can not access it?

I just got this new router/modem in one from comcast when I upgraded my internet, before this everything worked fine.  Now I cant get my server running for anything, I have disabled all firewalls allowed everything I can, searched all I can think of to search, but I can not access my IP (web server).

Before I had local IP's in the form of 192.168.1.0 now they are 10.0.0.0

After messing with my server as much as I was comfortable with, I decided to just install xampp and keep testing things with that until I get it working.

It has to be something with this modem router, but I can not figure it out.  So again...

**How can my port be visible yet I can not access it?**

I can access it locally (I.E. 10.0.0.50) I'm trying to get external access.

- windows firewall is off
- xampp conf allows all
- xfinity firewall is off

-- modem/router model
--- Model: TG1682G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some routers, port 80 cannot be used for purposes other than accessing the routers config page - Some internet providers also prevent port 80 traffic for various reasons.

I would use port 8080 instead for HTTP on your webserver. Do a rule forwarding port 8080 to port 80 on the IP address of the webserver.

If you require your old IP then you will have to change the IP of the router to 192.168.1.1 - This *should* also change the DHCP range automatically. Some routers (TG582N for example) Don't change the range.

Also, turn your firewalls back on!

Comment: well something happened doing this =) now going to my IP accesses the router.  In the router settings there is an option for allow remote access for support more or less screenshot http://i.imgur.com/Tje2UyB.png so would using port 8080 be best still?  I set xampp to port 2738 (random) and opened that port but myip:2738 still fails to load

Comment: so to recap now my ip opens my router login page, and i have put http on port 2738 and it still fails to load. =(  but it loads locally (10.0.0.2:2738)

Comment: Is the web-server on 10.0.0.2?

Comment: You need to create a new service on the tg1682g called websrv and start/end ports 2738, The firewall rule should then be added. Service websrv and IP address being the IP address of the webserver.

Comment: yes the websrv is on 10.0.0.2 and the service has been created, although navigating to my ip still opens the xfinity router rather than my apache page, and going straight to the port (IPADDRESS:2738) fails to load =/

Comment: Hey johnny, I'm sorry everything seems to be working lol, got on my phone disconnected wifi and loaded myip:2738 and it loaded, so i switched it all back to port 80 in the modem and apache conf and my ip now opens apache.  just on the local machine it doesn't and I have flushed / cleared everything I can =/

can you verify that http://its.dirtrif.com loads a directory?